# How to fix NoneType error in Python Binary Search Tree?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, nodes, nonetype, python-class

I'm creating a basic binary search tree program where the nodes have to be strings however, I keep getting this error:
`'builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addNode'`

I'm a bit confused because I thought you had to declare the children nodes as None. My code is below (please excuse the messiness and extra print statements):

```
class BinarySearchTree:
  #constructor with insertion value & left/right nodes as None
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None
  
  #function to insert node
  def addNode(root, data):
    #when tree doesn't exist
    if root == None:
      return BinarySearchTree(data)
    else:
      #when node is already in tree
      if root.data == data:
        return root
      #smaller values go left
      elif data < root.data:
          root.left.addNode(data)
      #bigger values go right
      else:
          root.right.addNode(data)
    return root

  #function to find smallest node value (to help with deletion)  
  def smallestNode(root):
      node = root
      #loop goes to lowest left leaf
      while(node.left is not None):
          node = node.left
      return node

  #function to delete node
  def removeNode(root, data):
    if root == None:
      return root
    #when node to be deleted in smaller than root, go left
    if data < root.data:
      root.left = root.left.removeNode(data)
    #when node to be deleted in bigger than root, go right
    elif data > root.data:
        root.right = root.right.removeNode(data)
    ##when node to be deleted in the same as root...
    else:
        #when node has only 1 or 0 children
        if root.right == None:
            move = root.left
            root = None
            return move
        elif root.left == None:
            move = root.right
            root = None
            return move
        #when node has 2 children, copy then delete smallest node
        move = root.right.smallestNode()
        root.data = move.data
        root.right = root.right.removeNode(move.data)
    return root

  def findNode(root, data):
    #if current node is equal to data value then return the root
    if root.data == data or root == None:
      return root
    #if current node is greater than the data value then, search to the left
    elif data < root.data:
      return root.left.findNode(data)
    #if current node is less than the data value then, search to the right
    else:
      return root.right.findNode(data)

def createBST(keys):
  root = BinarySearchTree(keys[0])

  for i in range(1,len(keys)):
      root.addNode(keys[i])
  return root

print('Hi! Welcome to the Binary Search Tree Builder')
print('Here are your options below:')
print('1) Build new tree')
print('2) Add a node')
print('3) Find a node')
print('4) Delete a node')
choice = int(input('What would you like to do?: '))
if choice == 1:
  nodes = list(input("Enter the strings you would like to build your tree from (separate by a space): ").split())
  print(nodes)
  tree = createBST(nodes)
  print(tree)
```

I'm wondering where exactly is this error coming from and how can I fix it? Also, if you see any other problems occuring in my code, please let me know!

Comment: The Exception should say which line it occurs on! You can also step through and set breakpoints in a program like this with the [pdb module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) `python -m pdb myprogram.py`

Comment: The error happens when you do `root.left.addNode(data)`, because you never put anything into `root.left`.  Fixing this problem won't make your program work; the whole design is flawed.  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflated the notion of "tree node" and "tree".  What you have there is a mixture of the two.  Remember, the first parameter to ALL member functions should be "self".  Replacing "root" by "self" might make your problem more clear.

So, you might create a `BinaryTree` class, which has a single member called `self.root` that holds a `BinaryTreeNode` object, once you have a node.  The nodes will hold the `left` and `right` values, each of which will either have `None` or a `BinaryTreeNode` object.  The node class probably doesn't need much code -- just `self.left` and `self.right`.

The `BinaryTree` class will have an `addNode` member that knows how to traverse the tree to find the right spot, but when you find the spot, you just set `self.left = BinaryTreeNode(...)`.  A node does not know about the tree, so a node does not know how to add new nodes.  That's a function of the tree itself.

Does that make your path forward more clear?

Comment: Your general guideline to creating a bintree doesn't solve his problem.

Comment: The error he has is because of a fatally flawed design.  Fixing the error will not lead him to a solution.  He needs to start over.